# Bounding the integral of a $C^1$ function

Tags: calculus, sobolev-spaces

Supopse that $\Psi \in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, $\Psi(x) \geq - C_0 \, \forall x$ and $|\Psi'(x)| \leq C_1|x|^q+C_2 \, \forall x$. Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. Under these assumptions how can I bound $\int_{\Omega}\Psi(u)$ by a constant? ($\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$).

Edit: typo with $r$ instead of an $x$.

Comment: Consider $\Omega$ to be a ball $|x|<1$, $n=5$, $u(x)=|x|^{-1}\in H^1(\Omega)$, $\Psi(u)=u^6$. The integral is infinite. What's wrong with this example?

Comment: Surely that $u$ isn't $H^1$?

Comment: It is, $|\nabla u|^2\sim |x|^{-4}$, $x\to0$, is integrable in $\Omega$.

Comment: Why does the bound for derivative have $r$ in it? Do you really mean to bound the integral by a constant independent of $u$, or by a constant times something involving $u$?

Comment: If I could bound it in terms of $u$ that would be helpful. Edited out the $r$, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating the inequality for $\Psi'$ we obtain  $\Psi(x)\le B_1|x|^{q+1}+B_2$ where $B_1,B_2$ are constants. Conversely, the choice  $\Psi(x)= |x|^{q+1}$ satisfies the hypotheses. Therefore, the problem could be equivalently stated as: estimate the $L^{q+1}$ norm of $u$.

If $q\le 1$ and $\Omega$ has finite measure, we get  $\|u\|_{L^{q+1}(\Omega)}$ bounded by $\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ which is a part of $H^1$ norm.

If $q>1$, we need [Sobolev embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) which requires some boundary regularity, such as $\partial \Omega$ being Lipschitz. The embedding places $u$ in $L^p $ with $p=2n/(n-2)$. So, if $1+q\le 2n/(n-2)$, we have an estimate; otherwise there is no bound for $L^{q+1}$ norm. The idea of counterexample was given by Andrew in a comment (you can cap off $|x|^{-\epsilon}$ and smoothen it to get a $C^1$ example with arbitrarily large $L^{q+1}$ norm).